# how to work around a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cors

I have two node servers on localhost:3000 and localhost:4000.
I call 4000 from 3000 and get the following error.

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Any suggestions for this error?

Comment: add `Access-Control-*` headers in the responses sent by `4000`

Comment: You add CORS support to your server to permit cross origin access.  A google search on CORS should show you how.  Since you showed none of your server code, we can't exactly advise you very specifically (we don't even know what server framework you are using).

Comment: perhaps something [here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=enable+cors+in+node+js) will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 4000 server is a express based node server, use "cors" package to solve it like below

```
    var cors = require('cors');
    .....
    app.use(cors());
```

Where app is an express application.